# with Excel, generate 0 with n% probability OR generate 1 with (1-n)% probability

Tags: probability, excel

(first of all I simplified my question)

Depending on the input info below, I want to create proper excel function in output part.

What I require verbally in output part under "*status (0 or 1) column*" is

Depending on the value of "*accumulated age*", generate 0 (zero) with corresponding probability in input part, else generate 1 (one) with (1-corresponding) probability.

For example, for the time being, since value under accumulated age is 1 (one), 0 (zero) should be generated with 5% probability OR 1 should be generated with 95% probability.

I checked up on excel statistic functions, I searched in google but I couldn't find my answer.

**input info**

```
accumulated      Prob. of Status = 0
age 
1                       5%
2                       12%
3                       22%
4                       25%
5                       28%
6                       7%
6+                      1%
```

**output part**

```
accumulated age         status (0 or 1)
       1                       ?
```

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make Excel draw a number from a standard uniform distribution and return a 1 when that value if less than the probability you are lookig for and 0 otherwise. The exact commands depend on the language used by Excel. In the German version it is: `=WENN(ZUFALLSZAHL() <A1;1;0)`

Comment: you & google translator helped me. Your ratio was 99% :). thanks, regards

Comment: For those wondering, in English versions that would be `=IF(RAND() < A1; 1; 0)`. BTW, you could also just write the logical statement `=RAND() < A1` and have the cell automatically output `TRUE` or `FALSE`.